# get search value from one view to other codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter and PHP.

I have search box and I have two views in my project related to this. My first header.php view has search input box and in second view search.php is displaying results. Here I need to get search value to display like (10 results found for "search value should be here").

Here is my header.php view:

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="content _relative row-fluid">                                   
        <a id="menuCollection" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">                                    
            <input type="text" id="search" class="span12" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off"/>
            <i class="modern-pictograms-search">&#115;</i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my search.php view.

```
<div class="search-result font-large"><?php echo count($value); ?> results found
    <span class="font-bold">(this is the place i need to get search value)</span>
</div>
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Show us the code of controller & Model first .

Comment: to start with if you are doing a normal form submission the search textbox needs to have a name="search" fields so that it can be picked up by the PHP. If your doing the submission with AJAX forget what I said. Also to make it display on the page you could do something like, `<span class="font-bold"><?= $this->input->post('<name of you search field>') ?></span>`

Comment: iam doing submission with ajax. but this thing does not work for me.

Comment: the problem is no one can help you because we have no idea what the vars are that are being sent by the AJAX and what your controller is doing. How are you accessing the posted var in your controller? because you will need to access it in the same way or assign it to a var that is injected into your views.

Comment: you can either make the search a form that posts directly to the search controller then use the textbox value to do whatever or on the search controller, have the index function accept an argument then you can pass the value of the textbox to it then use it for whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps may be it will help you to solve your problem:
make chances in your files as i mention it.
header.php - view

```
<html>
...
<form action='controller/method' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='search' />
    <input type='submit' value='search' />
</form>
```

search.php - view

```
...
<div class='results'>
<?php foreach($results as $result){ ?>
<div><?php echo $result; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
...
```

search.php - Controller

```
class Search extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('database');
}

public function index(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('yourtablename');
    $this->db->where('yourcondition'.$this->input->post('search'));
    $data['results']=$this->db->get();
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('searchview',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```